# Changing Unity Rigidbody.centerOfMass throws off AddRelativeTorque() calculations

Tags: rigidbody

This is an odd one, that has me kind of stumped. If I execute the code:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(0, 1000, 0);
}
```

I get this:

[image]

Normal, expected behavior. The (car in this case) rotates fine around Y. But if I try and change the center of mass,

```
void Start()
{
    rigidbody.centerOfMass = new Vector3(0, -0.2, 0.9);
}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque(0, 1000, 0);
}
```

[image: test]

The car spins on all 3 axis. AddTorque has the same problem. It is as if AddRelativeTorque/AddTorque are not accounting for the moved position of the center-of-mass. This was done in an empty Scene with the car floating at 0x 0y 0z.

Comment: I've seen issues in the past where updates to the physics engine's internal data don't get processed eagerly, but may be delayed, leading to unexpected behaviour in the meantime. Does using [Physics.SyncTransforms](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SyncTransforms.html) or [Rigidbody.ResetInertiaTensor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.ResetInertiaTensor.html) change the results you get at all?

Comment: No combination of those two seems to change anything. AKA only Sync, only tensor, then sync+tensor and tensor+sync.

Comment: The first thing I see is that the Local Center of Mass and the World Center of Mass are the same, but the position of the object isn't at zero. Or am I missing something about the World Center of Mass property?

Comment: The object is at zero, but the car spins around the center of mass, so the transform changes, but not the world center of mass.